# Pagination for activity feed to use new criteria if no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm building an activity feed that shows you what your friends have been up to. I'm able to paginate friends data with the following query:

```
friend_ids = current_profile.friend_ids
@activities = Activity.where(profile_id: [friend_ids]).order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])
```

I'd like to add logic for when there is no more content from your friends to then use second degree connection data and then use all public activity. Is there a straight forward way to do that?

The approach that I'm thinking is to add a variable that says if the current page is referring to `friends` or `friends_of_friends` or `everyone` so then the query is updated with the correct friend_ids and will exclude previous friend ids.

Is there a simpler solution? Or code that you could point me to that solves the problem of bubbling out activity feed results when no results are found with pagination?

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari's default records `per_page` is 25, so you could use that to find out what the last page number will be, and use that conditionally to pull in other data.

Another option might be to make sure `@activities` length is 25 (or however many number of records your max is per page).  If it's less, you know you've reached the end of your data and you can act accordingly.